# What is the official way to Calculate star dates and how can this be done in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

This question is written to help me understand how a StarDate is calculated using the method invented by Gene Roddenberry, and how I may implement that method into PHP.

Some methods that I have toyed with (but do not match or come from any official source)

```
echo date('Ym') . '.' . date('d');  // 1404.13

// 946684800 = 2000-01-01 00:00:00
// End date format, is - 14293.49631
// Accuracy is approximately every 0.33 seconds per tick.
echo floor((((((time() - 946684800)/1000)/60)/5)*0.009513655) * 100000000) / 100000;
```

I have found several resources online which appear to do calculations, however they are inconsistent.  The Wikipedia entry on this has very little detail on this process.

In the event that the official method is not accurate, I would like some assistance in developing one.  The proposed concept would not stray from the concept of using the century as the first digit, the "season" for the second digit, and use the seconds since that century started as the difference with fractional seconds as the right side decimal portion.

### For the official method, I could only find the following links (or similar) aside from wikipedia

http://www.hillschmidt.de/gbr/sternenzeit.htm

http://www.stoacademy.com/tools/stardate.php

http://www.trimboli.name/stardate.html

### For the create our own method

A problem I encountered is that a real day according to the earths roation (not solar day), is 24 hours, 56 minutes and 4.1 seconds, and PHP's idea of EPOCH (aka  `date('Y', 0);` is `1970`.

For this to work, the calculations must begin at the year 2000, and take into account the earth's rotation days (so actual day), in seconds/fractions of seconds.

For this method, I would like to know how I can convert the current date, minus 2000 years, and obtain the actual time elapsed according to the time for a full rotation of earth -- not 86,400 seconds/day as that is not accurate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @papirtiger - Nothing about star-date format on there. It should be assumed that I already know how to work with the `date()` / `time()` / `DateTime`  objects.  I need to know what the exact method of calculating a stardate is with php examples.

Comment: Following [wikipeadia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardate), the star date is not related to days, months and years in that way.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on a Star Trek Stackexchange site? Does one even exist? EDIT: Maybe http://movies.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: There is no "official" method. They simply selected blocks of dates and assigned them to writers to keep the time progression logical. There is no official "Stardate XXX = Gregorian Date YYY" conversion.

Comment: While it is already true what MarcB said, let me follow wikipedia again: `Each percentage point is roughly equivalent to one-tenth of one day`. This means the highest accuracy would be `day/10`. This will be not enough for (most) database operations at least not in early 21st century ;)

Comment: @JaredFarrish - no, I am asking about a conversion process for PHP -- not what happened on stardate XXXXX.XX .

Comment: @hek2mgl - If we can put our brains together, there must be some method that would work well for stardate calculations based on GMT (UTC) of course.  I think the STO site has something pretty close, however I can not find the calculations used.

Comment: From the wiki, for example, the first digit (4) represented the 24th century, the next digit (1 for example) represented the season. (which we can use the julian calender for season or divide the year into quarters instead and use that for simplicity), the remainder represents the day/time in some format ---  im thinking possible seconds from year start would be appropriate -- or somehow from century start (which would be very accurate -- more so than typical julian based stamps)

Comment: I guess to do this calculation -- will add to the Q --- how to accurately get seconds elapsed from century start.  (added)

Comment: Then your question is confused; are you asking which is the *correct approach* or *how to implement a **specific** approach*? The latter is appropriate for SO, but you need it to be specific to be a valid question.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - ideally, Gene Roddenbery's method, however if that proves to lack in accuracy, then something else that would be accurate. I do not feel that Wikipedia accurately represents the methods used for calculating stardates.  As an aside, when i run `echo date('Y', 0);` it shows 1970 as 'epoch' ... Which isn't bad, but i suppose in order to be accurate I should begin the calculation at `2000`.

Comment: According to this >> [Actual Time per Day](http://www.universetoday.com/14700/how-long-is-a-day-on-earth/), the solution to this puzzle is getting increasingly complex.

Comment: Let me think and revise the question .  I would like to understand this better -- if no valid format exists, we should create one.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - question has been revised for clarification on this as to what I am looking for.

Comment: From reading http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Stardate I surmise that the stardate was merely a method of not having to state the "real" (Julian Calendar) date. The Star Trek Guide (the series "bible") states: "Pick any combination of four numbers plus a percentage point, use it as your story's stardate." Also, the stardate is dependent on location, speed etc. (see Gene Roddenberry's explanation: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Stardate#The_Making_of_Star_Trek) I suggest making up a definition yourself that approx. matches the series and sticking to it.

Comment: @Thomas - excellent answer. What is baffling me now, is how to get actual earth rotation seconds rather than the approximate for the pseudo calculation. -- since clearly the stardate stuff is seemingly not possible unless we want to account for earths speed.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Why would a *star* date need to account for *Earth's* speed? It would surely be based on whatever standardised "day" was used to organise shifts on board ship.

Comment: As I understand it stardates have little to do with our current system for keeping track of time except that it has been (will have been?) agreed that a standard day is 24 hours.
The more I think about it the less sense stardates make. (What if you're on a planet with a rotation of 26 hours?).
What are you actually trying to achieve? Creating a more precise dating system or simply converting stardates to the Julian calendar?

Comment: @Thomas - Stardates as I understand are based on a factor of earth rotation being the core concept (since logging is relative to earth). However, time shifts play a role as per the speed of the ship (aka, moving at light-speed causes a time differential where time on the ship is relative, time outside passes at a different rate -- hence why speed of ship plays a role).  To keep it simple, I would like to start with just the base of 23hrs 56 minutes and 4.1 seconds as per the real rotation time of the planet (or 86164.1 seconds) as the actual basis for one earth rotation day.

Comment: @Thomas - not this method does not require timezones as those are based on solar days, not earth rotation days. (partial reference : http://pds.jpl.nasa.gov/planets/special/earth.htm ) (23.93 = 86256 seconds)

Comment: All - You're beating a dead horse.  If you want to keep going, please add to one of the *many* posts here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=stardate

Comment: @MattJohnson - I didn't know about that site.  I reviewed quickly and seems people are generally having an issue with calculating stardates with any usable accuracy level. After some digging, I have found a method, however it needs some tuning as it is hung up on a divide by error. It does take into account light-speed velocity as a starter and uses IERS for the 1 rotation for relativity.